# Customise bubble sizes for plotly scatterplot in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, plotly, scatter-plot

I suspect this is a simple coding issue, but I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong:

I'm running plotly in a Jupyter notebook and want the bubbles of a scatter plot to correspond to one of the features.

I include 5 features:

1. Dimension A (x),
2. Dimension B (y),
3. Municipality (the bubbles),
4. Province (colour),
5. Municipal Size.

There are several municipalities per province; the code below nicely assigns the same colour to municipalities of the same province.

```
figure={'data': [
                go.Scatter(
                    x=df[df['Province'] == i]['Dimension A'],
                    y=df[df['Province'] == i]['Dimension B'],
                    text=df[df['Province'] == i]['Municipalities'],
                    mode='markers',
                    opacity=0.7,
                    marker={
                        'size': df['Size'],
                        'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
                    },
                    name=i
                ) for i in df.Province.unique()
            ],
            'layout': go.Layout(               
                xaxis={'title': 'Dimension A'},
                yaxis={'title': 'Dimension B'},
                height=700,
                width= 1200,
                margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 10},
                legend={'x': 0, 'y': 1},
                hovermode='closest',
                autosize = False,
            )     
}
iplot(figure)
```

However, when I try to assign the size of the bubble to the "Size" feature, it goes weird. It *does* change the size of the first municipality's bubble. But the output also sees the first municipalities' value applied to every other province's first municipality (in the order it appears in the df). Maddening. Wisdom massively appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the data:

```
Municipalities,Province,Dimension B,Dimension A,Size //
!Kheis,NC,0.79,1.39,4.22 //
//Khara Hais,NC,0.61,4.75,4.97 //
Abaqulusi,KZN,0.44,4.43,5.32 //
Aganang,LP,0.55,2.56,5.12 //
Albert Luthuli,MP,0.66,3.56,5.27 //
Amahlathi,EC,0.20,3.33,5.09 //
Ba-Phalaborwa,LP,0.22,4.33,5.18 //
Baviaans,EC,0.10,1.95,4.25 //
Beaufort West,WC,0.68,3.04,4.70 //
Bela-Bela,LP,0.60,3.87,4.82 //
Bergrivier,WC,0.53,2.77,4.79 //
Bitou,WC,0.68,5.00,4.69 //
Blouberg,LP,0.37,4.34,5.21 //
Blue Crane Route,EC,0.70,2.20,4.56 //
Breede Valley,WC,0.88,4.67,5.22 //
Buffalo City,EC,0.67,6.57,5.88 //
Bushbuckridge,MP,0.87,5.14,5.73 //
Camdeboo,EC,0.10,1.61,4.71 //
Cape Agulhas,WC,0.42,3.00,4.52 //
Cederberg,WC,0.73,2.94,4.70 //
City of Cape Town,WC,0.73,7.74,6.57 //
City of Johannes,GA,0.65,7.81,6.65 //
```

Comment: Please, provide an excerpt of our DataFrame in order to make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @sentence. I'm not sure the data I provided above is an improvement? I think it's something with the loop...

Comment: Have you tried `'size': df[df['Province'] == i]['Size']` inside the marker dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the `size` key in `marker` dictionary from:

```
'size': df['Size'],
```

to:

```
'size': df[df['Province'] == i]['Size']
```

and you get:

[image]